# MVC 5 - How can I map an object to an Action when that object is a property of the view model for the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a **login view model** defined as such.

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public String Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Password { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// The default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public LoginViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

And my **master page** takes a **base view model** defined as:

```
public abstract class CommonViewModel
{
    #region Properties
    public LoginViewModel LoginModel { get; set; }                
    #endregion

    #region Functions

    /// <summary>
    /// The default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public CommonViewModel()
    {

    }

    #endregion
}
```

In **master layout** I have a **login form**. This form is laid out as such.

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">
    <div class="form-element">                            
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginModel.Username, Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginUsername, new { @class = "login-form-label" })                            
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginModel.Username, new
        {
            @class = "login-form-input login-form-input-common required",
            @autofocus = String.Empty,
            @placeholder = Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginUsername
        })
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginModel.Password, Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginPassword, new { @class = "login-form-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginModel.Password, new
        {
            @class = "login-form-input login-form-input-common required",
            @placeholder = Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginPassword,
            @type = "password"
        })
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginModel.RememberMe, Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginRememberMe, new { @class = "login-form-label" })
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.LoginModel.RememberMe, new
        {
            @class = "login-form-input login-form-input-common",
            @placeholder = Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginRememberMe
        })
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <input type="submit" class="login-form-submit login-form-input-common" value="@Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginLoginLabel">
    </div>
</form>
```

When I submit to the account controller, I don't have the login view model mapped.

```
/// <summary>
/// Logs the user into the application.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The login view model uses to login.</param>        
/// <returns>The view you were trying to get to.</returns>
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Models.ViewModels.Common.LoginViewModel model)
{

}
```

The view model is always the default empty values of null for username and password. How can I get the login model to map in the account controller login action?

I can't map to the common view model as I get an error that I can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: There are a couple options. 1. You remove the `abstract` from your Common vm. 2. Don't use a Common vm. 3. Use jquery to create the model and pass it to the Login.

Comment: The concept of the question isn't so much about the common view model but rather how I can map a controller to a model that is a property of the page's view model. I've encountered this scenario often not involving common view models. For example, what if you have a view model which has 5 separate objects and you have 5 action calls that take one of each of the 5 objects. It would break as well on that.

Comment: short answer is: you can't. MVC will bind to your "root" model whatever it is that the controller action is expecting.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 it should be CommonViewModel not LoginViewModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason why you are receiving `null` is because you are sending the data based on the model of the view which is `CommonViewModel`, if you take a property

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginModel.Password, new
                            {
                                @class = "login-form-input login-form-input-common required",
                                @placeholder = Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginPassword,
                                @type = "password"
                            })
```

and if you see the `rendered html` the name will be  `LoginModel.Password` but in the action you are trying to get `LoginViewModel`  which has no property `LoginModel.Password`

so your action should be

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(CommonViewModel model)
{
 var loginmodel= model.LoginModel; //here you can access the properties like loginmodel.Password
}
```

**Update**

another solution is to name the `Html Helpers` same as the name of `properties` of `LoginViewModel` so your view will be

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">
    <div class="form-element">                            
        @Html.Label("Username", Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginUsername, new { @class = "login-form-label" })                            
        @Html.TextBox("Username", new
        {
            @class = "login-form-input login-form-input-common required",
            @autofocus = String.Empty,
            @placeholder = Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginUsername
        })
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        @Html.Label("Password", Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginPassword, new { @class = "login-form-label" })
        @Html.TextBox("Password", new
        {
            @class = "login-form-input login-form-input-common required",
            @placeholder = Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginPassword,
            @type = "password"
        })
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        @Html.Label("RememberMe", Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginRememberMe, new { @class = "login-form-label" })
        @Html.CheckBox("RememberMe", new
        {
            @class = "login-form-input login-form-input-common",
            @placeholder = Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginRememberMe
        })
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <input type="submit" class="login-form-submit login-form-input-common" value="@Resources.MasterPageStrings.LoginLoginLabel">
    </div>
</form>
```

and your action will be

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Models.ViewModels.Common.LoginViewModel model)
{

}
```

Comment: When I tried this I got an error that I can't instantiate an abstract class. I'll have to do it again to find out exactly where it occurred to give more information.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 i have updated my answer with another solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your Login action so that it takes a CommonViewModel instead of a LoginViewModel.

Or better pratice, separate the code for the view into a partial view, set model of that view to LoginViewModel and render the partial like this :

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_LoginView", Model.LoginModel )
```

(assuming that the model type on your base view is CommonViewModel)

Comment: When I tried this, I got an error stating I could not do that because the commonviewmodel is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Partial View was made for this kind of situation.
Create a partial view and paste your login HTML. Keep the model of partial view as LoginViewModel and render it in the master page. 
That's it!